# C# use of unassigned local variable....confused

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

trying to iterate with this for loop and input int from user into array. I am getting an error and don't understand why..

error: Error    1   Use of unassigned local variable 'array'

```
using System;

namespace Lab16
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array;
        int value;

        Console.Write("How big of an Array? ");
        int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("First Value: ");
            value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       -->  array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(value);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array variable isn't initialized.  Writing this should fix it:

```
int[] array = new int[arraySize];
```

(Note, of course this needs to go *after* you've read *arraySize* from the console...)

```
int value;
Console.Write("How big of an Array? ");
int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] array = new int[arraySize];
```

And one more problem ... your for loop as written is going to go out of bounds.  Should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Local *variables* in C# are not `initialized`/assigned implicitly. Here in your code snippet, you need to create an array.

```
 int[] array=new int[arraySize];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the array once you know how big it should be.

You also need to iterate from `0` to `arraySize-1` - so I changed your `<=` to `<`:

```
    Console.Write("How big of an Array? ");
    int arraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] array = new int[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Value: ");
        int value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    }
```

If the user enters `10` for the length, you will initialize the array to length 10 - and then you can access elements `0` to `9`, which is 10 separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array, but you declare it before you know the size it needs to be.

```
using System; 


namespace Lab16 
{ 
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        int arraySize; 
        int arrayValue;

        Console.WriteLine("How big of an Array? "); 

        while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arraySize))
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("How big of an Array? ");
        }

        int[] array = new int[arraySize]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value of element {0}: ", i));
            while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arrayValue))
                 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value of element {0}: ", i));
            array[i] = arrayValue;
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```